# Dependecy trouble when testing AngularJS with Karma

Tags: angularjs, testing, dependency-injection, karma-runner

I'm having trouble with dependencies in Karma test scenario.
When preparing environment looks like this:

```
    beforeEach(module('printecAdminApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function(restService) {
            testRestService = restService;
            injector = angular.injector(['ng']);
        }));
```

and test scenario like this:

```
it('simple REST GET', function() {
        injector.invoke(function($http) {
            var getResult,
                        restOpt = testRestService.prepareRestCallObj(); 
                       //returns {method: 'GET', url : '...'}

            runs(function() {
                        $http(restOpt).then(.....
            });
            waitsFor(function() {
                return getResult;
            }, 'get result', 50);           
            runs(function() {
                expect(getResult).toEqual({"status" : true});
            });
        });
    });
```

It works ok. But I would like to move `restService` dependency from preparing environment part of code to scenario, because I would like to get rid of static `testRestService` variable. Like $http. But if I try to do it same way - declaring in with $http

```
injector.invoke(function($http, restService) {
```

I get this error: **Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: restServiceProvider <- restService**

Any idea how should I do it? Should I assign it to injector in preparation code?

Thx for any answer or hint

Comment: did you inlcude beforeEach(module('your module name'))?

Comment: Yes I did - I forgot to put that in code above. Look now, code is edited